# How to add default array to column in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, default-value, rails-migrations

Now i am trying add default value to database column. I am trying with the following migration file.

```
def change
  add_column :user_preferences, :preference, :default => "Media, Responsibilities, Email"
end
```

When i am trying to `rake db:migrate` it show the following error.

```
undefined method `to_sym' for #<Hash:0x007fc33683e658>/db/migrate/20141120090990_add_preference_to_user_preference.rb:3:in `change'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for #<Hash:0x007fc33683e658>
/db/migrate/20141120090990_add_preference_to_user_preference.rb:3:in `change'
```

In model

`serialize :preference`

I want to add default to that `preference` column. Help me.

Comment: What is the `datatype` of `preference` column?

Comment: @Pavan I gave `:text` but it shows the error `Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'preference' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `user_preferences` ADD `preference` text DEFAULT`

Comment: In `Mysql2`,the `datatypes blob/text` can't have `default values`.Instead change the datatype to a `varchar` or `char`.